# Awk partial string match

Tags: awk, gawk

So I'm trying to partially match strings in one field and then use that field with another field from a seperate file,

Example of inputs -

input1.txt:

```
example/world
example/forever
```

input2.txt

```
example123
example234
```

expected output.txt:

```
example123/world
example234/world
example123/forever
example234/forever
```

So basically using AWK seperate input1.txt into 2 fields using -

```
awk -F"/"
```

which means for line one $1 is `example` and $2 is `world`

which then checks whether input2.txt contains `example` by partially matching $1 in input2.txt, it then finds those matches and combines them with input1's $2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v file2="input2.txt" -F'/' '{
  while ((getline line < file2) > 0){
    if (line ~ "^"$1) print line FS $2
  }
  close(file2)
}' input1.txt
```

This does basically what you described. For each line in `input1.txt` all lines from `input2.txt` are read and compared against the beginning of `$1`.
If matched, `input2.txt`'s line is printed with separator `/` and `$2`.

Comment: Thanks that solved my question :)

Comment: That's doing a partial regexp match, not a partial string match. You'll notice the difference when your input contains regexp metacharacters. The OP didn't say it had to be a partial match at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to to a partial string match:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="/" }
NR==FNR {
    strings[$1]
    next
}
{
    for (string in strings) {
        if ( index(string,$1) ) {
            print string, $2
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk input2.txt input1.txt
example234/world
example123/world
example234/forever
example123/forever
```

If you want the match only at the start if the string then just change `index(...)` to `index(...) == 1`.

Comment: Your output does not match the expected output. Order is wrong.

Comment: @fpmurphy With applications like this the order rarely matters so it's not worth complicating the code to address something that almost certainly isn't an issue. If it is an issue then the OP can tell us and then it's a simple tweak to change the output order. Also, your own answer will produce output in random order (actually hash order) too courtesy of you also looping using the `in` operator and the fact you got output in the same order as shown in the question given this particular data set is just pure co-incidence.

Comment: -1 for output that does not match sample output provided by OP.

Comment: @fpmurphy Then give yourself `-1` too because your code works **exactly** the same way mine does wrt the output order. The fact that with a given run of the code with a given input on a given machine using a given awk version produced one order of output for me and a different order of output for you is complete chance. Change your input or run your script with a different awk version or on a different machine and you'll get a different order of output.

Answer (score -1):

Another `awk` solution based on sample files provided:

```
$ cat demo.awk
BEGIN { FS="/"; while ((getline < "input2.txt" ) > 0 ) { s[i++] = $0 } }

{ for (i in s)
    if (s[i] ~ "^"$1) { print s[i] FS $2 }
    # alternative tests
    # if (index(s[i], $1)) { print s[i] FS $2 }
    # if (index(s[i], $1) == 1) { print s[i] FS $2 }
}
```

Output:

```
$ awk -f demo.awk input1.txt
example123/world
example234/world
example123/forever
example234/forever
$
```

Comment: That's doing a partial regexp match, not a partial string match. You'll notice the difference when your input contains regexp metacharacters. It'll also spin off into an infinite loop on a getline failure, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for how to call getline when necessary.